# Reading and writing to the same file from different programs

Tags: python

I have two programs written in python and converted to one-file exe using auto-py-to-exe.
the first program writes to a file, which is read by the second program. The problem is when the second program wants to read the file the same time as it is being written, the code stops with a permission error.
The solutions that seemed to work are:

1. Using time management which is not useful in my case, since the reading and writing times are not constant.
2. I could check if the file is accessible, which might be a solution, however, I suppose it would raise an error if while reading the file, the writer tries to change the file.
3. I could use the size of the file to check if writing to the file has been finished, and then execute the reader, however, this does not seem to be both logical and pythonic!
4. I found some solutions using os.pipe(), but to be honest, I couldn't understand what the process does. If this is a solution, I would be glad to have it explained in simple English.

That's it. Any suggestions?

P.S: OS is windows and I am using Python 3.9

Solved:

Thanks to the replies and suggestions, I didn't know that the try except commands accept ErrorType. Thus, I solved the problem by using 'except' and 'PermissionError'. the code runs in a loop and it is checked again in a few seconds.

However, the drawback is this: the reading time should be less than the time the writer comes back to rewrite the file! In my case, as suggested by friends, I combined the two programs so they are run sequentially.

Comment: The permissions error is explicitly a Windows thing. Better operating systems allow concurrent file access.

Comment: That said -- it sounds like you haven't looked into file locking?

Comment: IMHO, this cries for a pipe...

Comment: What is the use case where you need to read and write a file from two different programs? Maybe there is another fundamental solution so you don't have to bother with the one you are asking about.

Comment: I too smell XY problem here. OP has correctly identified some potential solutions and their possible issues, which indicates a fundamental design problem.

Comment: You cannot concurrently and reliably read and write to a flat file on any operating system unless the processes involved are somehow cooperating (such as through some kind of locking mechanism). Try using a database

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your suggestion. unfortunately, I am a Windows user. However,  I have to dig deeper in file locking. I didn't know anything about it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
You are right. At first, I was trying to do the whole process in one program, however, additional parameters were added to the problem, and I had to slice the program so I can access and rerun the second part, while nothing is changed in the first part. Maybe, you are still right and I have to join the programs and think of another solution to run different parts separately, Thanks anyway. I appreciate it.

Comment: Why not catch the exception and try to read again after a slight pause?

Comment: You can run the two parts sequentially.